# Wifi stopped working in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 - replaced wifi card, still not working

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, thinkpad

I'm running a Thinkpad T430s with a week-old install of Windows 10 Pro. After a few days, the wifi disconnected and won't reconnect.

Lenovo T430s running Windows 10 Pro with most recent updates (anniversary). Wireless card is Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205. It is on the whitelist for the Lenovo T430s.

Suddenly last week the wireless connection disconnected. Network Settings has the wifi switched to Off. Clicking it to switch to on changes nothing - it shows as on, but connections don't work, and if I close the Network Settings window and re-open, the switch is back to off.

Windows 10 will not switch off of airplane mode. Clicking the mode button does nothing - the icon stays blue. Ethernet works fine.

Things I have tried:

- Run all updates through Windows Update.

  - Run all updates through Lenovo Companion, including a BIOS update.
  - Reset the BIOS to factory settings.
  - Made sure WLAN is enabled in the BIOS.
  - Made sure that the hardware wifi switch is set to on. Switched it back and forth between on and off, to make sure what I thought was on was actually on.
  - Replaced the wifi card with another card. Made sure that the cables are connected firmly and the card is seated and the screw replaced. Both the original and replacement cards are Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205.
  - Rescanned for hardware changes in Device Manager. Uninstalled the wireless card. Disabled it. Enabled it. Checked for driver updates.
  - Booted into a live Ubuntu 14.04.3 live mode from USB. Ubuntu says that the wifi is disabled by hardware switch. `rfkill list all` shows

  `0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
          Soft blocked: no 
          Hard blocked: yes`

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hardware problem. I followed the Lenovo manual to access the ribbon cable. It was disconnected from the switch. Reseating it fixed the problem.